# Does it matter if I have more questions than answers?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, answers

I really want to ask a question, except I'll have more questions than answers. I don't want to appear like I'm not adding to the community in any way. However, there is no questions that haven't already been sufficiently answered by someone else, because I'm slow, and I don't want to repeat their points. I might just quickly answer Connor's question. No one take it please.

So, is it okay to ask a question if you don't have more answers than you have questions asked?

EDIT: So, I answered Connor's question. B. Clay Shannon's question is pretty tricky, I don't know much about theater so I shan't answer that. abc1234's question and 'UK vs. US editions of fiction' are pretty hard for me. I'm a bit scared to answer publishing and edition or whatever questions because I've never got published myself. I also can't answer the ones about writing software because I never use it, so Godzilla2y's question can't be answered by me. Luckily, I was able to answer Connor's question though, all the other ones about writing (not publishing/software) have already been answered.

Comment: Please don't answer a question unless you have a good answer that you are confident of and could support with research or examples. That is in no way constructive and just adds noise to the site.

Answer (score 9):

It is perfectly okay to only ask questions. Don't feel pressured to answer questions.

Comment: When should I answer a question that already has an answer? @what

Comment: @DanielCann Whenever you feel that you have a better answer or can add something that the others missed.

Comment: Agreed! Please ask as many questions as you like. Asking good questions isn't easy (it's not supposed to be) and we need questions more than we need answers. And this is particularly difficult site to ask good questions for.

Comment: @DanielCann I've answered questions which already had an accepted answer. If you have something to contribute, go right ahead. More perspectives are always welcome.

Comment: @DanielCann I will second everything the others have said here. I'm here to learn myself, and I do most of that through questions. The longer I spent here though, the more I realized that I actually knew the answers to some of the questions being posted. And so I began answering as well. No one's going to judge you for having more questions than answers; in fact, questions are probably more valuable than answers.

Answer (score 3):

In the nature of things, people will start out in any field with more questions and answers. As you progress and gain more experience you will have fewer questions and more answers.

It is not a contribution to the community to provide an answer that is not well founded in experience and/or research. It is not a contribution to give "I would do it this way" answers that come out of no more experience or knowledge than the person who answered the question possessed. Brainstorming isn't an answer per the conventions of Stack Exchange.

Asking good questions, however, is a very definite contribution to the community. Without questions there are no answers. A good question is a service to everyone who may ever have the same question since it serves to generate answers that may be useful to everyone who searches for an answer to that question in the future. This is why you gain reputation for asking good questions as well as for giving good answers.

In short, ask when you have a good question to ask. Answer when you have a good answer to give. Both are valuable contributions to the community.

Answer (score 3):

This community is has much more of a lack of good questions than of good answers.  So having more questions than answers is actually a net gain for the community.